# Where's the link back from howtogeek to SO?

Tags: discussion, league-of-justice, howtogeek

I was wondering what SO gets in return to linking to and talking about howtogeek; I couldn't find a link to any of the so family of sites for example over there.

What's in it for SO?

What will it get from the other (yet to come) members of the league?

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/how-to-geek-at-superuser-new-moderator-footer-link and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/is-howtogeek-com-part-of-the-so-network

Comment: Typical fanboys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that Super User is [all public](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/super-user-now-public/), the How-To-Geek has posted an article plugging it:

[Are You a Super Geek? Here’s the One Site You Must Belong To](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3430/are-you-a-super-geek-heres-the-one-site-you-must-belong-to/)

Also, the footer on every page now contains:

> Our Friends
>
> - stackoverflow.com [programming]
> - serverfault.com [sysadmin]
> - doctype.com [web design]
> - superuser.com [computing]

So it seems to be all good :)

Answer (score 7):

Jeff has [said](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/howtogeek-and-stack-overflow/#comment-29483) that a link back isn't necessary until SuperUser officially launches in mid-August:

> We probably don’t need to link back until SU is out of beta, I think.. mid-August is the target date!

Still, the fact that I can't find *anything* on howtogeek.com referring to the role he now has on SuperUser bothers me a little.

Comment: oh ye of little faith...

Answer (score 3):

Have some patience; it's not like I would invite someone into our League of Web Justice I didn't trust!

Comment: That's the twist of every season of 24.

Comment: Well, maybe they don't trust you, Jeff ;)

Comment: lol @ random    .